# How to add external arguments in python script?

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I want the user to provide some external arguments while calling a python script from command line, what changes I suppose to make inside my python script to add this functionality?

Comment: Maybe you should show your python script that is in question?

Comment: Did you do some preliminary research first? Go through this doc, perhaps it'll help. https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html

Comment: Either use `sys.argv` or `argparse`

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you are looking for

pass arguments in command line.

```
$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

access it using sys.argv which gives list of arguments that you entered above

```
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```